# Modal position changes depending on trigger location

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am building a web widget that opens a modal window. The window opens as expected when the trigger link is at the top of the page. But when the trigger is at the bottom of a long page (that requires scrolling), the modal window is clipped/truncated above the viewing area.

Regardless of where the modal window is triggered, the HTML is appended to the body of the page, so I don't understand what's causing the issue.

I would appreciate some help.

js code: https://textfilter.me/widget.js

example / demo : https://textfilter.me/privacy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not javascript. It's css. In this case change `position:absolute` to `position: fixed` in modal class. voila.

Comment: I should have caught that, but I wouldn't have. Thank you.